# Firebase command throwing errors in terminal

Tags: firebase

Firing any firebase command in terminal throws this error

```
firebase : File C:\Users\Fresh\AppData\Roaming\npm\firebase.ps1 cannot be loaded because running
```

scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at 
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ firebase login
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess

[image: firebase commands throw this error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is running VS code as Administrator or just use another cmd, to open default cmd, just type `cmd` in `powershell` available in vs code, which is restricting from running script.

Comment: Running as admin doesnt seem to be solving it

Comment: Running cmd in vscode terminal seems to have done the trick, thanks

Comment: run it in administrator mode and still there is errors